# Showing a matrix $A$ is positive definite

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, positive-definite

I am trying to show that the following matrix is positive definite:
$$A=\begin{pmatrix}
2 & -1 & 0 \\
-1 &2 &-1 \\
0 & -1 &2
\end{pmatrix}.$$
A matrix $A\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ is positive definite if $x^TAx>0$ (there are other ways to show the matrix $A$ is positive definite, e.g. by calculating the deteminant of each principal matrix,  but I am not concerned with this).

\begin{align}
x^TAx&=\begin{pmatrix} x_1 & x_2 & x_3\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}
2 & -1 & 0 \\
-1 &2 &-1 \\
0 & -1 &2
\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} x_1 \\ x_2 \\ x_3\end{pmatrix} \\
&=2x_1^2-2x_1x_2+2x_2^2-2x_2x_3+2x_3^2. \tag{1}
\end{align}
How is this greater than zero? I have tried to complete the square, but I have not been successful.

Comment: $(x_1-x_2)^2+(x_2-x_3)^2$ plus some other squares.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [Gerry Myerson](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/8269/gerry-myerson)'s question [comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3575773/showing-a-matrix-a-is-positive-definite/3575777#comment7352155_3575773) indicates, you have

$$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
& 2x_1^2 - 2x_1x_2 + 2x_2^2 - 2x_2x_3 + 2x_3^2 \\
& = x_1^2 + (x_1^2 - 2x_1x_2 + x_2^2) + (x_2^2 - 2x_2x_3 + x_3^2) + x_3^2 \\
& = x_1^2 + (x_1 - x_2)^2 + (x_2 - x_3)^2 + x_3^2 \\
& \ge 0
\end{aligned}\end{equation}\tag{1}\label{eq1A}$$

Note it is $0$ only if $x_1 = x_2 = x_3 = 0$, so the result is always positive for any non-zero vector.

Regarding the stated result in your textbook, is it missing the $-$ signs or did you not put them in?

Comment: They missed the signs, and I was left scratching my head haha thank you for your response!